# Displaying 5 histograms on 1 axis - julia

Tags: matplotlib, histogram, julia, plotly

referring to this link [Displaying 3 histograms on 1 axis in a legible way - matplotlib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9497524/displaying-3-histograms-on-1-axis-in-a-legible-way-matplotlib) to display 3 histograms on 1 axis in python, l tried to do the same in julia but the dic function is not recognized.

here is the code for julia. the function dict is not recognized.

```
using PyCall
@pyimport matplotlib.pyplot as plt



a=vec(rand(1:1000,400,300))
b = vec(rand(200:700,400,300))
c = vec(rand(300:1200,400,300))

common_params = dict(bins=20, 
                     range=(-5, 5), 
                     normed="True")

plt.subplots_adjust(hspace=.4)
plt.subplot(311)
plt.title('Default')
plt.hist(a, **common_params)
plt.hist(b, **common_params)
plt.hist(c, **common_params)
plt.subplot(312)
plt.title('Skinny shift - 3 at a time')
plt.hist((a, b, c), **common_params)
plt.subplot(313)
common_params['histtype'] = 'step'
plt.title('With steps')
plt.hist(a, **common_params)
plt.hist(b, **common_params)
plt.hist(c, **common_params)

plt.savefig('3hist.png')
plt.show()
```

l tried to use : plotly and l confronted some problems also. Here is the code using plotly

```
using Plotly

x0 = randn(500)
x1 = randn(500)+1


trace1 = [
  "x" => x0,
  "type" => "histogram"
]
trace2 = [
  "x" => x1,
  "type" => "histogram"
]
data = [trace1, trace2]
layout = ["barmode" => "stack"]
response = Plotly.plot(data, ["layout" => layout, "filename" => "stacked-histogram", "fileopt" => "overwrite"])
plot_url = response["url"]
```

the returned error is :

```
WARNING: deprecated syntax "[a=>b, ...]" at /home/anelmad/Desktop/stage-inria/code/HTreeRBM.jl/my_tree/random_data/graph_try.jl:20.
Use "Dict(a=>b, ...)" instead.
ERROR: LoadError: MethodError: `convert` has no method matching convert(::Type{PlotlyJS.Plot{TT<:PlotlyJS.AbstractTrace}}, ::Array{Dict{ASCIIString,Any},1}, ::Dict{ASCIIString,Any})
This may have arisen from a call to the constructor PlotlyJS.Plot{TT<:PlotlyJS.AbstractTrace}(...),
since type constructors fall back to convert methods.
Closest candidates are:
  PlotlyJS.Plot{T<:PlotlyJS.AbstractTrace}(::Array{T<:PlotlyJS.AbstractTrace,1}, ::Any)
  PlotlyJS.Plot(::PlotlyJS.AbstractTrace, ::Any)
  call{T}(::Type{T}, ::Any)
```

Answer (score 3):

Julia has its own interface to matplotlib called `PyPlot`. (you didn't *really* expect you'd simply type `@pyimport` and then just write python code into julia and magically have it all work, did you? :D )

See [here](https://gist.github.com/gizmaa/7214002) for examples on how to use `PyPlot`; The [`hist`](https://gist.github.com/gizmaa/7214002#histogram) plot in particular needs some special syntax to differentiate it from the julia native `hist` function ([check the code for its example](https://github.com/gizmaa/Julia_Examples/blob/master/pyplot_histogram.jl)).

Here is your code translated to PyPlot to the best of my ability (works in Julia v0.6.0)

```
import PyPlot

a = vec( rand( 1:1000,   400, 300 ))
b = vec( rand( 200:700,  400, 300 ))
c = vec( rand( 300:1200, 400, 300 ))

common_params = Dict( :bins   => 20, 
                      :range  => (-100, 1300), 
                      :normed => true )

PyPlot.subplots_adjust( hspace=.4 )

PyPlot.subplot( 311 )
PyPlot.title( "Default" )
PyPlot.plt[:hist]( a; common_params... )
PyPlot.plt[:hist]( b; common_params... )
PyPlot.plt[:hist]( c; common_params... )

PyPlot.subplot( 312 )
PyPlot.title( "Skinny shift - 3 at a time" )
PyPlot.plt[:hist]( (a, b, c); common_params... )

PyPlot.subplot( 313 )
common_params[:histtype] = "step"
PyPlot.title( "With steps" )
PyPlot.plt[:hist]( a; common_params... )
PyPlot.plt[:hist]( b; common_params... )
PyPlot.plt[:hist]( c; common_params... )

PyPlot.savefig( "3hist.png" )
PyPlot.show()  # PS, this is unnecessary in PyPlot. All commands show instantly
```

I'm not sure why you chose a range of (-5,5); this was causing a problem on the third subplot. I've changed it to something more reasonable here just to show you this works.

Here's the result below:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The "julia" code looks like plain Python to me, which is not how PyCall works. Thus, dict() is not a Julia function, but you can write the following to get a Julia dictionary:

```
common_params = Dict("bins" => 20,  "range" => (-5, 5),  "normed" => true)
```

Your error message for the Plotly example doesn't match your code. The code `using Plotly` references a different package than the error message indicating that you are using `PlotlyJS` (Plotly and PlotlyJS are different packages, with [PlotlyJS.jl](https://github.com/spencerlyon2/PlotlyJS.jl) being the recommended package to use for julia v0.4 and newer).